# Go Get the Six Six-Pack

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, no-computers

And fill with right Mathematical operands and enjoy.[image]

Six Relations shown in the pictures are missing the right operands.

You can only use plus, minus, multiplication, division signs in between the sixes.

Operations are carried out from left to right.

Comment: So to be clear, we can't use parenthesis?

Comment: Yes..just the signs mentioned..order left to right..as shown

Comment: I think in this case, you should explicitly parenthesize the expressions. That would be clearer than an external instruction that "operations are carried out from left to right."

Comment: Thx..will do in future problems

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got 6 of them:

> 1. $13 = 6 / 6 +  6 + 6$
>  2. $42 = 6 / 6 + 6 * 6$
>  3. $48 = 6 * 6 + 6 + 6$
>  4. $66 = 6 + 6 * 6 - 6$
>  5. $108 = 6 + 6 + 6 * 6$
>  6. $180 = 6 * 6 - 6 * 6$

Comment: That’s fast..time to enjoy them

Comment: Nooo I'm to slow  :(

Answer (score 3):

> 1. ÷++ 2. ÷+× 3. ×++ 4. +×- 5. ++× 6. ×-×